# Is there any way to differentiate between new and retained MQTT message?

Tags: mqtt

Like the title, can I differentiate between new and retained MQTT message? 
And how to know when the message are published by client? All of this **without** specify  timestamp string in topic or message.

Answer (score 5):

The retained flag is used by a client to indicate to the broker that the broker should keep the message as the "last known good" value for the topic being published to.

When the broker talks to a client, the retained flag has a different meaning: If the flag is set on a message, it means that the message is one that was published as a retained message *before* the client subscribed to the topic. In other words it is a "stale" message. When the broker sends a message that does not have the retained flag set, it means that the message has just been published by another client and can be considered to be fresh/new.

As @hardillb says, there is no way of determining whether a fresh message you receive was designated as a retained message by the publishing client.

Answer (score 2):

There is a flag in the MQTT publish packet header the indicates a message is retained.

But assuming you are trying to spot messages delivered twice this won't help as a publisher could publish a new retained message just as a subscriber reconnects and it would be delivered for the first time with the retained bit set.

As for a message timestamp, no, if you want one you will have to include it in the payload.